# My function will give correct answers on only one call but not on multiple

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, initialization, do-while

I'm making a code for converting Decimal numbers to Binary(university assignment). If I only do DecToBinary(5) it gives me 101, and if I only do DecToBinary(6) it gives me 110, but when i do both of these statements in main() it gives me 101110101 when it should just give me 101110(joining the two answers above). I don't understand what is going on since it should just call DecToBinary(5) and print 101 then (without adding a newline character) call DecToBinary(6) and print 110.

```
void DecToBinary(int dec){

    int temp[64]; //64 is just a max value
    int i,j;

    while(dec>0){
        temp[i]=dec%2;
        dec=dec/2;
        i++;
    }

    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        printf("%d",temp[i-1-j]);
    }


}
```

Comment: You forgot to initialize `i`.

Comment: `Warning: uninitialized local variable 'i' used` - if your compiler isn't giving you a similar warning, time to turn up your warnings and treat them as errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized the variable `i`. This means that the behaviour of your program is undefined, as the value of `i` may be different of `0` which is what you want.

To correct it, you just have to initialize `i` when declaring it, meaning `int i = 0`

Answer (score 1):

The variable `i` is not initialized

```
int i,j;
```

so the function has undefined behavior.

You need to initialize it before the while loop.

Also the while loop should be substituted for a do-while loop. Otherwise the value 0 will not be processed correctly. For example

```
i = 0;

do
{
    temp[i++] = dec % 2;
} while( dec /= 2 );
```

Also as the function does not process negative numbers then its parameter should have the type unsigned int

```
void DecToBinary( unsigned int dec )
```

Answer (score 0):

Always initliaze variable. Check i and j in your case.

Comment: j does not have to be initialized as it is into the ```for``` loop

Comment: Yes not required here but always a good habbit for better code.